# java script for calculation not working

Tags: javascript

i have a code which works half perfect but its not updating the fields: 3R Profit Formula:, Target Selling Price:, Total Target Profit:, Target Gain:, well its actually updating the fields but i still need to use the TAB button and go to certain fields before it populates the changes but i want it to be automatically updating as soon as i changed a related fields...

what its supposed to do is to automatically update the fileds 3R Profit Formula:, Target Selling Price:, Total Target Profit:, Target Gain:, but cant seem to make it worked...it stopped working on 3R Profit Formula fields so i cant continue further...

here are the formula that i am using, lets just focus on a single field now: 3R Profit Formula

first we need to find

Risk/Reward Factor = Risk Amount / Shares

then 3R Profit Formula = 3 * Risk/Reward Factor

so what i want is whenever i changed the value on either Risk Amount or Shares field, the changes would automatically reflect on the 3R Profit Formula field

i have the code below,

```
<table width="634" height="224" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

  <tr>
    <td width="135">Risk Amount:</td>
    <td width="81"><input type="text" name="risk" id="risk" size="8"/></td>
    <td colspan="2">How much you can afford to lose?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No. of Shares:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="shares" id="shares" size="8"/></td>
    <td colspan="2">Number of  shares bought</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Risk/Reward Factor:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="factor" id="factor" size="8" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td colspan="2"><strong>R</strong> = Risk Amount / No. of Shares</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3R Profit Formula:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="3r" id="3r" size="8" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td colspan="2">3R formula  to get target selling price</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

and this is my java script codes, seemed to be working only up to Cut Loss: field,

**UPDATED JAVA SCRIPT CODE**

```
// Risk/Reward Factor
$(function () {
    $("#risk, #shares").keyup(function () {
        var r = parseFloat($("#risk").val());
        var s = parseFloat($("#shares").val());
        if (isNaN(r) || isNaN(s) || s<=0) {
            $("#factor,#3r").val('');
            return false;
        }
        $("#factor").val((r / s).toFixed(3)); // Risk/Reward Factor
        $("#3r").val((r / s * 3).toFixed(3)); // 3R Profit Formula
    });
});

// Capital
$(function() {
    $("#buy, #shares").keyup(function() {
        var b2 = parseFloat($("#buy").val(), 10);
        var s2 = parseFloat($("#shares").val(), 10);
        if (isNaN(b2) || isNaN(s2)) {
        $("#capital").val('');
        return false;
        }
        $("#capital").val(b2 * s2);
        updatecapital();
    });
});

// Cut Loss
$(function() {
    $("#buy, #risk, #shares").keyup(function() {
        var b = parseFloat($("#buy").val(), 10);
        var i = parseFloat($("#risk").val(), 10);
        var h = parseFloat($("#shares").val(), 10);
        if (isNaN(b) || isNaN(i) || isNaN(h)) {
        $("#cutloss").val('');
        return false;
        }
        $("#cutloss").val(b - i / h);
    });
});

function updatecutloss() {
        var v1 = parseFloat($("#risk").val(), 10);
        var v2 = parseFloat($("#shares").val(), 10);
        var v3 = parseFloat($("#buy").val(), 10);
        if (isNaN(v1) || isNaN(v2) || isNaN(v3)) {
        $("#cutloss").val('');
        return false;
        }
        $("#cutloss").val(v3 - v1 / v2);
    };

function updatecapital() {
        var x1 = parseFloat($("#shares").val(), 10);
        var x2 = parseFloat($("#buy").val(), 10);
        if (isNaN(x1) || isNaN(x2)) {
        $("#capital").val('');
        return false;
        }
        $("#capital").val(x1 * x2);
    };

$(function() {
    $("#buy, #factor").keyup(function() {
        var bu = parseFloat($("#buy").val(), 10);
        var fa = parseFloat($("#factor").val(), 10);
        if (isNaN(bu) || isNaN(fa)) {
        $("#targetprice").val('');
        $("#targetprice").change();
        return false;
        }
        $("#targetprice").val(bu + (3 * fa));
        $("#targetprice").change();
     });
});

$(function () {
    $("#risk, #shares, #bp").keyup(function () {
        var r = parseFloat($("#risk").val());
        var s = parseFloat($("#shares").val());
        var bp = parseFloat($("#bp").val()); // buy price
        if (isNaN(r) || isNaN(s) || s <= 0) {
            $("#factor,#3r,#capital,#targetprice,#totprofit,#gain").val('');
            return false;
        }
        $("#factor").val((r / s).toFixed(3)); // Risk/Reward Factor
        $("#3r").val((r / s * 3).toFixed(3)); // 3R Profit Formula
        if (isNaN(bp)) {
            $("#bp").val('');
            return false;
        }
        $("#capital").val((bp*s).toFixed(3));
        var targetprice = bp + (r/s*3);
        $('#targetprice').val(targetprice.toFixed(3));
        $('#totprofit').val((s*targetprice).toFixed(3));
        $('#gain').val((bp*s).toFixed(3));
    });

    $("#bp").keyup(function () {
        var r = parseFloat($("#risk").val());
        var s = parseFloat($("#shares").val());
        if (isNaN(r) || isNaN(s) || s <= 0) {
            $("#factor,#3r").val('');
            return false;
        }
        $("#factor").val((r / s).toFixed(3)); // Risk/Reward Factor
        $("#3r").val((r / s * 3).toFixed(3)); // 3R Profit Formula
    });

});
```

Comment: to use stackoverflow website well [ssce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Too much code can you be precise in your problem?

Comment: edited now removed the codes for the fields that are working...whats left are the fiwlds which arent automatically populating the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in one place:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#risk, #shares").keyup(function () {
        var r = parseFloat($("#risk").val());
        var s = parseFloat($("#shares").val());
        if (isNaN(r) || isNaN(s) || s<=0) {
            $("#factor,#3r").val('');
            return false;
        }
        $("#factor").val((r / s).toFixed(3));
        $("#3r").val((r / s * 3).toFixed(3)); // 3R Profit Formula
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g76eS/1/

Comment: this is pretty simple and neat...but i cant seem to modify this and make it worked for my other codes as well...:( i need the changes to affect my other 3 fields as well...

Comment: `<tr>
    <td>Target Selling Price:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="targetprice" id="targetprice" size="8" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total Target Profit: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="totprofit" id="totprofit" size="8" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Target Gain:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="gain" id="gain" size="8" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>`

Comment: formula for Target Selling Price = Buy Price + 3R; for Total Target Profit = No. of Shares * Target Selling Price and for Target Gain = Total Target Profit - Capital

Comment: Thanks, seems to be no problem, are also `Buy Price` and `Capital` custom values from inputs?

Comment: `Buy Price` value is a variable as well as `No. of Shares` fields, `Capital` field value depends on them, `Capital = Buy Price * No. of Shares`

Comment: when i say `Buy Price` and `No. of Shares` fields a variable, it means user can change their values and `Capital` depends on either value

Comment: works perfectly in jsfiddle...exactly what i needed but just wont work when incorporated to my existing java codes, please see update above...i tried the new fiddle and wont work as well...

Comment: on ur new fiddle, formula for `Target Gain` is `Target Gain = Total Target Profit - Capital` this seems wrong, if i understand it correctly `$('#gain').val((bp*s).toFixed(3));`

Comment: Hi Joe, you're right it was wrong, updated the formula. Try to replace all the scripts above with the single event handler in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g76eS/8/ (now it seems to work good)

Comment: everything works perfectly now with a nice and clean code...unlike my codes earlier...thanks a bunch...

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your problem is you are correctly triggering the:

```
 $("#risk, #shares").keyup(....
```

function but this is then setting the factor value. However setting the factor value won't trigger the key up event.Which means the 3r field won't be populated.

Changing to

```
    $("#factor").change(function() {
        var x = parseFloat($("#factor").val(), 10);
        $("#3r").val(x * 3);
    });
```

And then adding:

```
 $("#3r").change();
```

at the end of your $("#risk, #shares").keyup(.... function after you have set the value would trigger the new function.

Suggested code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#risk, #shares").keyup(function() {
        var r = parseFloat($("#risk").val(), 10);
        var s = parseFloat($("#shares").val(), 10);
        if (isNaN(r) || isNaN(s)) {
        $("#factor").val('');
        $("#factor").change();
        return false;
        }
        $("#factor").val(r / s);
        $("#factor").change();
     });
});

// 3R Profit Formula
$(function() {
    $("#factor").change(function() {
        var x = parseFloat($("#factor").val(), 10);
        $("#3r").val(x * 3);
    });
});
```